# При создании проекта с областями на asp.net core не работает валидация и не срабатывают пост-методы в контроллере

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, валидация

При создании Web-проекта с областями (areas) на asp.net core не работает валидация и не срабатывают пост-методы в контроллерах, которые находятся в областях. Делаю тот же самый проект без областей (areas), все работает.
Кусок контроллера с пост-методом:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(CreateUserViewModel model)
{
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
                User user = new User { UserName = model.UserName, Email = model.Email };
                var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("ViewAll", "Users");
                }
                else
                {
                    foreach (var error in result.Errors)
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
                    }
                }
       }
       return View(model);
}
```

Модель

```
public class CreateUserViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Пароль")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
```

В файле startup.cs маршрут определен

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "areas",
                template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}");
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

[image: Структура проекта]

Comment: Не могу показать больше скриншотов, не дает опубликовывать более двух ссылок имея репутацию менее 10 баллов. В input поле когда ввожу пароль выводит буквы, а не маску, также при нажатии на кнопку после заполнения формы происходит обновление страницы, пустая форма и адрес вместо http://localhost:65450/ac/users/create выводит http://localhost:65450/ac/users/create?

Comment: Get-методы работают нормально. Над контроллером стоит все как положено [Area("Ac")]
        public class UsersController : Controller

Comment: Редирект на несуществующую вьюху сделал специально в наджеде проверить его и получить exeption, на это внимание не обращайте. Использую VS 2017. В VS 2015 то же самое.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена. Нужно в каждую область (areas/[areaname] в папку Views копировать из корня проекта Views/Shared  файлы _Layout.cshtml, _ValidationScriptsPartial.cshtml, Error.cshtml, а также _ViewImports.cshtml из Views. Валидация заработала, пост-метод контроллера тоже. Всем спасибо. =)

Comment: Копировать данный список файлов в каждую область это значит плодить кучу повторяющегося материала в проекте, но другого выхода я пока не нашел.